# Minimax theorem as a consequence of Hahn Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, optimization, game-theory

Please I have difficulty relating the [minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem) to the Hahn Banach theorem in functional Analysis...minimax is a consequence of Hahn Banach but I just can't see it... Please I need someone who's good in analysis and optimization/game theory to help me.

Comment: It could help if you actually explain what the minimax theorem says.

Comment: You can check on Wikipedia for minimax theorem by Von Newmann, I'm using a phone to type so I can't type equations clearly

Answer (score 0):

For a proof of the standard Sion version, see:

> p. 5-6, Mertens, Jean-François, Sylvain Sorin, and Shmuel Zamir. *Repeated Games.* Vol. 55. Cambridge University Press, 2015.